# Telegram Bot — reset user settings on chat removing / clearing

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I am using Java library for Telegram Bots Api: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

The thing I'm wondering about — is it possible to detect when bot is removed from user contact list?
I would like to handle this event to delete user settings (such as language) from database, so next time user adds my bot, he can specify settings from scratch and not stucking on selected previously.

#### SOLUTION FOUND

I described my solution below.

Comment: Are you sure that is a good idea to reset user's settings when they send the /start command?

Comment: @ariaby I think this is pretty OK solution, because /start command is not displayed in popup command list, so it can't be picked up accidentally. It's designed to be sent only in 2 cases: 1) when user adds your bot for the first time; 2) when user bot's history is cleared and chat is restarted. If user sends /start command manually, he may expect exactly the same behavior as described above.

Comment: You might want to write your own answer and accept that, so people can vote for the answer.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yeah, I'll do it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found a possible solution.
 
Hope, it will help to somebody.

There's no need to handle bot removing, instead of this you can handle bot's *restart*, because first message bot receives everytime after user clears history or re-adds removed bot — is **/start** command. So receiveing **/start** command is a good point to reset previous settings and let user to specify them again.

Also see the discussion above: [Telegram Bot — reset user settings on chat removing / clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779401/telegram-bot-reset-user-settings-on-chat-removing-clearing#comment63082926_37779401)

Comment: Love it! This is particularly useful when bot is still in development state. Handing `start` command will be an intuitive way for bot developer to start conversation with user from the .. well, start. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because you won't receive a notification when user removes the bot. The only error you get is when you try to send a message to a user that has blocked the bot.

Answer (score 1):

While **/start** is working solution to recognize that user has restarted dialog with bot, now (September 2022) there is a way to get a **disconnect message**.

⚠️ *I'm using another  library and language, however shure that it's an API feature, not depending on language (i'm using: C# nuget Telegram.Bot ver 18.0.0)*

When user click to "Stop and block bot":

[image: Telegram Bot Info menu, Stop and block bot]

Telegram sends an update message (`Telegram.Bot.Types.Update`) with `ChatMemberUpdated` info (`MyChatMember` field) - datails on person , see example:

[image: Telegram.Bot.Types.Update, Telegram.Bot.Types.ChatMemberUpdated example]